# Jquery load outside iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, parent

I have a very strange problem, i have an iframe that is able to communicate with it's parent, but only in some certain ways. For an example i have this code in the iframe

```
$(document).ready(function(){
           parent.document.getElementById('target').style.display = 'none';
});
```

This hides a div called target in the parent page. Very nice. But this code wich is really what i want to do (loading page.php into the div called target) does not work even though its placed in the exact same way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
           parent.document.getElementById('target').load("page.php");
});
```

Does anyone know why?
Peace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#target', parent.document).load("page.php");
});
```

Give that a go

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you! Been rubbing my head for quite some time on this one. Great!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $(parent.document).find('#target').load("page.php");
});
```

you should work